# Turn date into string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, date

I am beginner and do a project where I fetch data and I should visualize data by chart bar, and fetched date looks like "09/2009" but I need it to turn into month "September". I tried to `toString()` method but in doesn't work. And I can't understand how I have to turn it and also where I have to add that data in chartBar code. And also my dates displayed in wrong way in chart bar[image] Here is my code:

```
  // const first_brewed = beerData.first_brewed;
  const [first_brewed, abv] = beers;
  console.log("beers!!!!", first_brewed);
  //  Think how I can turn 09/2020 date into September
  const dateString = first_brewed.toString();
  console.log(dateString, "Date String!!!!");
  return (
    <>
      {/* Chart Bar */}
      <div className="bar-wrapper">
        <BarChart width={600} height={300} data={beers}>
          <XAxis dataKey="first_brewed" stroke="#333" />
          <YAxis />
          <Tooltip />
          <CartesianGrid stroke="#ccc" strokeDasharray="5 5" />
          <Bar dataKey="abv" fill="#9772FB" barSize={30} />
        </BarChart>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

And one more question, I have to use date picker to filter by date and display it in chart bar and I also have filter by the beer percentage, can I use the same chartBar for both filters? Could you help, please.[image]

Comment: `fetched date looks like "09/2009"` so, it's a string , right?

Comment: split on `/` and then map to month name.

Comment: @HassanImam it is the string but I need it turn into months name as in task

Comment: Here's a really ugly way to do it ;) https://jsfiddle.net/jgspLz50/

Comment: simple as `new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: "numeric", month:"long"}).format(new Date(...dateString.split('/').reverse().map(Number), 0));`

Comment: I think that the date "09/2009" is already a string and that is the reason why `.toString()` doesn't work. What you could try to do is `new Date(first_brewed)` and then call a date function on it (e.g. if you only need the month's short name `.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'short' });`).

Comment: @ZulfiyaYumagulova If you can create a live example in [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new), we can easily solve your problem.

Comment: @DucktorDanny `new Date("09/2009")` results in `Invalid Date`

Comment: @phuzi true I didn't think of that part but seems like there is already an answer below that solves this problem as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can split your date string on `/` and extract month and year, then using date constructor create the date object and then get the month name using `toLocaleString()`.

```js
const dateStr = '09/2009';
const [month, year] = dateStr.split('/').map(Number);
const date = new Date(year, month - 1, 01);
const monthName = date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });
console.log(monthName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
const month = "09/2009".split('/')[0]
const date = new Date(month)
console.log(monthNames[date.getMonth()])
```

```
// const first_brewed = beerData.first_brewed;
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
const [first_brewed, abv] = beers;
console.log("beers!!!!", first_brewed);
//  Think how I can turn 09/2020 date into September
const dateString = first_brewed?.first_brewed?.split('/')[0]
const date = new Date(dateString)
console.log(monthNames[date.getMonth()])
return (
  <>
    {/* Chart Bar */}
    <div className="bar-wrapper">
      <BarChart width={600} height={300} data={beers}>
        <XAxis dataKey="first_brewed" stroke="#333" />
        <YAxis />
        <Tooltip />
        <CartesianGrid stroke="#ccc" strokeDasharray="5 5" />
        <Bar dataKey="abv" fill="#9772FB" barSize={30} />
      </BarChart>
    </div>
  </>
);
}
```

Comment: ```const date = new Date(month)``` why I have month undefined?

Comment: Oh sorry my bad, I have updated the answer. can you please check now.

Comment: Now I have an error ```react-refresh-runtime.development.js:315 Uncaught TypeError: first_brewed.split is not a function``` I checked first_brewed is an object but I can't understand why. Array I fetched looks like 
```abv: 4.5
attenuation_level: 75
boil_volume: {value: 25, unit: 'litres'}
ebc: 20
first_brewed: "09/2007"
} ```


ingredients: {malt: Array(3), hops: Array(5), yeast: 'Wyeast 1056 - American Ale™'}
method: {mash_temp: Array(1), fermentation: {…}, twist: null}
name: "Buzz"

Comment: Sorry to bother you, I again updated the answer can you please check.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Gives the same error. I tried to do  JSON.stringify(first_brewed) but than it undefined(((

Comment: can you please `console.log(first_brewed)` and tell me what is printed in the console..

Comment: looks like:{id: 1, name: 'Buzz', tagline: 'A Real Bitter Experience.', first_brewed: '09/2007', description: 'A light, crisp and bitter IPA brewed with English and American hops. A small batch brewed only once.', …}

Comment: in `first_brewed` you have `object`, you have to do this to get the date `first_brewed. first_brewed`, I have updated the answer, please check.

Comment: it gives me undefined

Comment: can you please console `console.log(first_brewed?.first_brewed)`, and tell me what is printed in the console

Comment: it gives me  undefined I can't understand why, I have in my App.js ```const [beers, setBeers] = useState([]);``` than I pass it ```<BarChart beers={beers} />```

Comment: it's okay, you need to console `console.log(beers)`, If `beers ` is object like `{id: 1, name: 'Buzz', tagline: 'A Real Bitter Experience.', first_brewed: '09/2007'.....`, then you need to console `console.log(beers?.first_brewed)` If `beers?.first_brewed` has value then you need to change this line `const dateString = first_brewed?.first_brewed?.split('/')[0]` to `const dateString = beers?.first_brewed?.split('/')[0]` please try this.

Comment: Can you confirm whether `beers` is an object or an array?

Comment: beers is undefined as well, but how I could display all data than?

Comment: I found my error!!! I tried to access to first_brewed in wrong way, I shoud it like: ```beers[0].fisrt_brewed ``` and now I have date and try to convert it.

Comment: yeah that's why I was asking you in beers have an object or an Array. well best of luck

Answer (score 0):

you can make a new function that change the two firsts components of the array dateString. This function can calculate the month as you want. I leave you the function I created, as well as the result it leaves on console

```
    function changeNumberString (num) {
     let date = new Date();
     if (0 < num && num<= 12) {
       date.setMonth(num- 1);
       return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-EN', { month: 'long'}).format(date);
     } else {
       return null;
     }
    }

t = "09/2020"
console.log(changeNumberString(t[0] + t[1]))
```

The result is:

```
   September
```

Comment: if change t = first_brewed it gives me null.